# New to WPF and Databinding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

So I'm new to WPF and C#, and teaching myself as I go.  The part I am stuck on now is databinding to a local database.  I've made applications in WinForms and VB.Net before, and can't seem to transfer my knowledge over.  For example, for a WinForm, I would create a  data source and table adapter, call the table adapter on the form and set a text box to display the data, for example:

(Me.TxtBoxName.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", Me.TBInventoryBindingSource, "InventoryName", True))

For WPF No matter what I do I cant get the data to bind to any type of control.  Even if I do a right click and try to use the wizard to create a data binding, it doesnt see the datasources Ive created.  Normally this is how i can figure stuff out.  Let the wizard do it, see what it adds, then research and learn...

Can anyone point me to some tutorials or something that breaks it down barney style? Most everything I have seen involves binding controls to each other or to a static dataset.

In my project I am connecting to a locally stored database.  I have both a SQL version and a MS Access version of the database.

Comment: Generally, you dont want to do data binding in code unless there is a good reason. Have you tried in XAML? Post some code that is failing and the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check following links. Hope it helps.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480226.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24192/Simple-Demo-of-Binding-to-a-Database-in-WPF-using

Comment: Thanks, these helped a bit, along with some books I ended up getting.  Biggest problem I had was VS2012 was not building my Data entities right and there were some methods that were not generated.